# Can we Read/Write Json data from/Into .js file using Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, local-storage

Localstorage have storage limit between 5MB to 10MB depends upon browser.My question is,Is there any way to store large json data into external .js file.so we can read/write data as like localstorage??

Comment: You don't mean on the client, do you?

Comment: I developing mobile app using phonegap.i m using localstorage for database.i want to increase size of that.localstorage hv its specific size.so i want to store my json data into external js file.so i can use it like localstorage..

Comment: Phonegap provides Storage API. Why not use that?

Comment: @Allen King.. Can you please provide me a link?

Comment: Here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: Thanks @Allen King I will try this.But I want to know by using js file can we store json data into that or read data from that file?

Comment: I am not an expert in js files but I can imagine using a global variable in a js file to store json should work. But using Storage API appears much cleaner and way of doing things because I don't know much about js variable life cycle.

Comment: There must be some API provided by phonegap to store data in local storage

Comment: I tried so much using that also.but it didn't works.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For PhoneGap (or Apache Cordova), you want to use the file system to write to the file. See the File plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) for more information.